# AFNetworking 2 - get UIImage from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, uiimage, afnetworking

I got the following input XML:

```
 <Company>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <IndustryId>1</IndustryId>
    <IndustriesID>
      <int>1</int>
      <int>2</int>
      <int>3</int>
    </IndustriesID>
    <Name>ClasOhlson</Name>
    <Icon>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKMAAAByCAYAAAA/DmEKAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAEFkb2JlIEltYWdlUmVhZHlxyWU8AABdDklEQVR4Xu2dB5hURfb2W0GCRPOuuua0hjUnzIoYwQSIKEFEgkgUJCg
```

How can I get `UIImage` from `<Icon>` tag? I am using AFNetworking 2.0. My code:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/GetAllCompanies", FPHostAddress];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

// Make sure to set the responseSerializer correctly
operation.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSXMLParser *XMLParser = (NSXMLParser *)responseObject;
    [XMLParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:YES];
    id parser = [CompaniesXMLParser new];
    XMLParser.delegate = parser;
    BOOL isParseSuccessful = [XMLParser parse];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Download failed. Error: \n%@", error.localizedDescription);
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                        message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

}];
[operation start];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating an application target to iOS 7 and above you should do this after get the string from parsed xml:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64Encoded options:0];
UIImage* icon = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
```

Otherwise, if the base iOS version of your app is something before iOS 7.0, you should download the files with category implementation from here:

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html

And do this:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataFromBase64String:base64Encoded]; 
UIImage* icon = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
```

Where **base64Encoded** is what you read from Icon tag.